# How to change the title of Front page in Composite C1?

Tags: c1-cms

I am new to composite C1 and just installed it on my server. I notice there is a menu item on top called "Front page", and I would like to change it to "Home". How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered here https://compositec1.codeplex.com/discussions/468992

In short:

1. Edit the page.
2. Switch to the Settings tab
3. Change the value in the Menu Title field
4. Save & Publish the page.